# How use VPN IP as outgoing IP only

Tags: vpn, windows-server-2012-r2

I have remote windows server and sstp/l2tp/pptp VPN client on this server.

The problem is if I connect to this VPN my current public IP lost and I can only access server with VPN IP.

If unchecked the outgoing gateway from vpn client both IP worked but my outgoing IP is not VPN IP.

The question is there any way to use VPN IP only as outgoing IP addrss? or making route on server that route internet traffic thought the VPN client?

Comment: too vague and not enough details, sounds like you should have your network tech setup loopback nat policies